# Control how web essential generates d.ts files from .cs files

Tags: c#, json, serialization, typescript, web-essentials

For example "Guid" types are ganerated as "any" type.

Uri type is generated as complex type:

```
{
    AbsolutePath: string;
    AbsoluteUri: string;
    Authority: string;
    DnsSafeHost: string;
    Fragment: string;
    Host: string;
    HostNameType: any;
    IsAbsoluteUri: boolean;
    IsDefaultPort: boolean;
    IsFile: boolean;
    IsLoopback: boolean;
    IsUnc: boolean;
    LocalPath: string;
    OriginalString: string;
    PathAndQuery: string;
    Port: number;
    Query: string;
    Scheme: string;
    Segments: string[];
    UserEscaped: boolean;
    UserInfo: string;
}
```

but in reality it is serialized as string.

So... Is it possible somehow to tell WebEssentials, how to serialize property types, 
either globally:

```
Guid -> string
Uri -> string
```

or locally property by property:

```
[TypescriptType(typeof(string))]
Guid Id {get; set;};
```

Of course, globally by project or solution is better.

Comment: i dont think `TypescriptType` comes from web essentials...

Answer (score 1):

It seems that Web Essentials can't do this (yet?). I'd suggest you two things:

- Use [TypeLITE](http://type.litesolutions.net/) (as we did).
- Fork it. Look into [IntellisenseParser.cs](https://github.com/madskristensen/WebEssentials2013/blob/master/EditorExtensions/Misc/CodeGeneration/IntellisenseParser.cs) and find `GetClassName`.

  - (Let me know if you have any progress with this. ;))

Comment: Just a thought: In `IntellisenseParaser.cs`here is a dictionary `_knownPrimitiveTypes`. Maybe if we added `guid` into it and pointed it to the type `string`? Having `guid`s as `string` would be at least a slight improvement over `any`